# Serious performance issues with Java SAX

Tags: java, sax, saxparser

I'm building an application that converts an SVG directly to a PDF. Because the SVGs can get quite large and they can be handled linearly, I decided to implement the XML parser with SAX. However, I am not getting the proper performance from the parser: It takes 20 seconds to handle a 45KB SVG file.

Profiling reveals that the CPU hog is in XMLParser's parse method. More specifically, it's taking all this time not to process the data, but just to read it in. It goes all the way down to java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0, where the CPU is spending 19 seconds.

Has anyone else had this problem? Does anyone know how to fix it?

The driver I'm using:

```
// Initialize SAX components
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

// Set System L&F
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

// Create a new file chooser
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileFilter(
        new FileNameExtensionFilter("SVG file", "svg"));

// Let the user choose an SVG file and convert it
if (fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Convert")
        == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File svgInput = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    File pdfOutput =
            new File(svgInput.getPath().replace(".svg", ".pdf"));
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(new SVGToPDFConverter(pdfOutput));
    URL inputURL = new URL(svgInput.toURI().toString());
    System.out.println("Working...");

    // Parse the file
    try (InputStream inputStream = inputURL.openStream()) {
        xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
    }

    System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

The start of the SVG file I've been testing with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="fill-opacity:1; color-rendering:auto; color-interpolation:auto; stroke:black; text-rendering:auto; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-miterlimit:10; stroke-opacity:1; shape-rendering:auto; fill:black; stroke-dasharray:none; font-weight:normal; stroke-width:1; font-family:'Dialog'; font-style:normal; stroke-linejoin:miter; font-size:12; stroke-dashoffset:0; image-rendering:auto;" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css">
  <!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator-->
  <defs id="genericDefs" />
  <g>
    <g style="font-size:14; fill:white; text-rendering:optimizeLegibility; color-rendering:optimizeQuality; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; font-family:'Calibri'; color-interpolation:linearRGB; stroke:white; font-weight:bold;">
      <rect x="68" width="54" height="17" y="2" style="stroke:none;" />
      <text x="73.4" xml:space="preserve" y="15" style="fill:black; stroke:none;">Dates (Ma)</text>
      <rect x="447" width="40" height="17" y="2" style="stroke:none;" />
      <text x="452.7" xml:space="preserve" y="15" style="fill:black; stroke:none;">Composition</text>
      <rect x="604" width="54" height="17" y="2" style="stroke:none;" />
      <text x="609.5001" xml:space="preserve" y="15" style="fill:black; stroke:none;">Isotopic Ratios</text>
      <text x="5" xml:space="preserve" y="32" style="fill:black; stroke:none;" />
      <text x="5" xml:space="preserve" y="43" style="fill:black; stroke:none;" />
      <text x="5" xml:space="preserve" y="54" style="fill:black; stroke:none;">Fraction  </text>
      <line x1="70" x2="70" y1="18" style="fill:none; stroke:gray; stroke-width:0.5;" y2="76" />
      <text x="73.4" y="32" style="fill:black; stroke-width:0.5; stroke:none;" xml:space="preserve" />
      <text x="73.4" y="43" style="fill:black; stroke-width:0.5; stroke:none;" xml:space="preserve">206Pb/</text>
      <text x="73.4" y="54" style="fill:black; stroke-width:0.5; stroke:none;" xml:space="preserve">238U</text>
    </g>
```

Comment: Where is the SVG being read from, and what happens if you read that data directly (without even processing it)? Is SAX reading a byte at a time, perhaps - wrap it in BufferedInputStream?

Comment: It's being read from an SVG file on my hard drive. I'm really not doing any processing right now (I'm in the middle of switching architectures). It's using BufferedInputStream.read down at the lower levels of SAX, I don't know if it's trying to read it byte by byte, though.

Comment: If it's being read from your hard drive, why is there a SocketInputStream involved?

Comment: @JohnZeringue Maybe you can show some code?

Comment: Does the SVG include any references, either external XML entities or images, which would do socket access (probably http)?

Comment: Do you have references to schema files in the xml?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Is there anything else that you'd like me to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your parser fetching dtd from "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd"

You can manually fetch that URL, store it as local file and than set custom handler, where can do dtd resolving.

I wrote some code, as example.

```
@Test
public void testParser() throws Exception {
    // Initialize SAX components
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
    File f = new File("/home/grigory/test.svg");
    saxParser.parse(new FileInputStream(f), new MyHandler());
    System.out.println("execution time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
}

private static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws IOException, SAXException {
        System.out.println("resolve: "+ systemId);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/grigory/svg10.dtd");
        return new InputSource(is);
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("start element '" + qName + "'");
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
    }

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        super.warning(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        super.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! This solved my problem completely! I don't have any prior experience with SAX and only a little with XML, so this isn't something that I probably would've come up with on my own.